# Setting up first schema.yml for Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to set up Symfony 1.4. I'm not new to MVC but this is my first attempt at Symfony. I've been following the documentation on symfony-project.org/reference/1_4 and I have a "Hello, World!" page.

I moved on to the next step -- database.

I did this (don't worry. localhost only :) ):

```
./symfony configure:database "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myblog" myblog myblog
```

Then I put this in my config/doctrine/schema.yml file:

```
Article:
  actAs: [Sluggable, Timestampable]
  columns:
    title:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    content:
      type: clob
    status: string(255)
    author_id: integer
    category_id: integer
    published_at: timestamp
  relations:
    Author:
      foreignAlias: Articles
    Category:
      foreignAlias: Articles
    Tags:
      class: Tag
      refClass: ArticleTag
      foreignAlias: Articles
Author:
  columns:
    first_name: string(20)
    last_name: string(20)
    email: string(255)
    active: boolean
Category:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
Tag:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
ArticleTag:
  columns:
    article_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    tag_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    Article:
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Tag:
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

But I'm getting this:

```
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ ./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_30022.yml
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticleTag.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseCategory.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticle.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseAuthor.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseTag.class.php
>> autoload  Resetting application autoloaders
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_autoload.yml.php
>> doctrine  generating form classes
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239

Fatal error: Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239
```

I tried several different example files for my schema.ywl, so I don't think it's flawed. I must have missed a step.

Something's not right, but I'm absolutely stumped. Any help will be very appreciated!

**Edit**
My original config/doctrine/schema.yml was:

```
Posts:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    columns:
      title: string(255)
      body: clob
```

**Edit 2**
Per Mike's request, I edited the file to be this:

```
Article:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    title:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    content:
      type: clob
    status: string(255)
    author_id: integer
    category_id: integer
    published_at: timestamp
  relations:
    Author:
      foreignAlias: Articles
    Category:
      foreignAlias: Articles
    Tags:
      class: Tag
      refClass: ArticleTag
      foreignAlias: Articles
Author:
  columns:
    first_name: string(20)
    last_name: string(20)
    email: string(255)
    active: boolean
Category:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
Tag:
  columns:
    name: string(255)
ArticleTag:
  columns:
    article_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    tag_id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
  relations:
    Article:
      onDelete: CASCADE
    Tag:
      onDelete: CASCADE
```

The error is:

```
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ ./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_79366.yml
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticleTag.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePosts.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseCategory.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticle.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseAuthor.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseTag.class.php
>> autoload  Resetting application autoloaders
>> doctrine  generating form classes
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239

Fatal error: Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$
```

**Edit**
For Mike's manual build suggestion, I get the same error on doctrine:build-filters and doctrine:build-forms:

```
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ php symfony doctrine:build-model
>> doctrine  generating model classes
>> file+     /tmp/doctrine_schema_91741.yml
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticleTag.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePosts.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseCategory.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseArticle.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseAuthor.class.php
>> tokens    /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BaseTag.class.php
>> autoload  Resetting application autoloaders
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_autoload.yml.php
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ php symfony doctrine:build-filters
>> doctrine  generating filter form classes
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239

Fatal error: Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ php symfony doctrine:build-forms
>> doctrine  generating form classes
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25

Fatal error: Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239

Fatal error: Call to a member function evictAll() on a non-object in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ php symfony cc
>> cache     Clearing cache type "all" for "frontend" app and "test" env
>> file+     /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_test-cli.lck
>> chmod 777 /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_test-cli.lck
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/test/config/config_config_handlers.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/test/config/config_app.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/test/config/config_settings.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_test-cli.lck
>> cache     Clearing cache type "all" for "frontend" app and "dev" env
>> file+     /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_dev-cli.lck
>> chmod 777 /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_dev-cli.lck
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_autoload.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_config_handlers.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_databases.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_app.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/dev/config/config_settings.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_dev-cli.lck
>> cache     Clearing cache type "all" for "frontend" app and "prod" env
>> file+     /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_prod-cli.lck
>> chmod 777 /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_prod-cli.lck
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_config_handlers.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_app.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/cache/frontend/prod/config/config_settings.yml.php
>> file-     /home/charlie/sfproject/data/frontend_prod-cli.lck
charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$
```

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Your new schema looks good, your original schema was bad.

This:

```
Posts:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    columns:
      title: string(255)
      body: clob
```

Should be:

```
Posts:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    title: string(255)
    body: clob
```

With the previous snippet, columns was at the same level as **actAs** which is why it's choking on trying to create a 'columns' class.

-- Edit --

Try running the build manually (should be able to swap out doctrine with propel if using propel):

```
php symfony doctrine:build-model
php symfony doctrine:build-filters
php symfony doctrine:build-forms
php symfony cc
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike. 

I don't think it's my schema file though. I tried your version of the file with columns on the same depth as actAs and changed the actAs to have the brackets -- and I get the same error.

And, like you said -- the new file looks good. 

It has to be something else. But what? :(

Comment: Try yours without the `[Sluggable, Timestampable]`, and use mine `{ Timestampable: ~ }`. It may be because timestampable is expecting a value due to the colon/tilde construct.

Comment: Please the original post's edit. I tried your change. 

I don't think it's the schema file. I didn't even write these files myself. They should be fine. 

It's something else.

Comment: Odd, which version of symfony you running?

Comment: charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ ./symfony -V
symfony version 1.4.16 (/home/charlie/sfproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib)


**To clearify -- another project (that I want to join) at my company is using Symfony 1.4, so I'm attempting to learn it. 
I'm using 1.4 because my company is still on 1.4 and I want to join another project.

Comment: Maybe it helps to know the version I'm using? 
`charlie@mystery:~/sfproject$ php -v

PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb  9 2012 05:59:43) 

Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies`

Comment: I even thought that maybe my editor (Netbeans) was messing up the spacing so I used nano. No dice.

Comment: 1.4 is still legit, so no worries, I run it on several projects b/c v2 is a complete rewrite, and don't have the time to relearn everything. I added an edit, see if that helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7550/discussion-between-mike-purcell-and-squirecd)

Comment: I edited my original post. I did the manual build and I get the same errors on doctrine:build-filters and doctrine:build-forms

Comment: Not really. If you edited the file on windows, you may wanna try a `dos2unix schema.yml` to remove any weird line breaks. If that doesn't work, you can try removing each table section and see if it finally builds, narrowing down where the issue may be.

Comment: Yes to trimming down the YAML file until it builds - I use that trick, it's very useful :)

Comment: Which entry was causing the breakage?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem lies in the classes generated with your old schema versions. Take a look at the first error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'columns' not found in /home/charlie/sfproject/lib/model/doctrine/base/BasePost.class.php on line 25
```

It's talking about the classes created before you renamed Post to Article (and it looks like you tried once with Posts). When you remove or rename models in the schema symfony will not remove the old class files for you, but it does provide a command to run which will find any orphan classes and prompt you to confirm their removal. The command is:

```
./symfony doctrine:clean-model-files
```

Use it to get rid of the old leftover classes and then, along with Mike's solution, you might just be in business.